# Replace the contents of an ExtJS component with arbitrary html

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a web app that uses ExtJS 4.1.  The javascript is all MVC.  I have a store that makes a JSON call to the server to get a single record containing html markup that I would like to replace the contents of one of my components with.  I can verify that my store is working correctly and my controller is working correctly, but the function I am using in my view, `setInnerHtml` is not working.

Here is my controller code:

```
Ext.define(appName + '.controller.Header', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: [ 'Header' ],
    models: [ 'Header' ],
    views: [ 'main.Header' ],
    refs: [{ ref: 'headerView', selector: 'header' }],

    init: function () {
        var headerStore = this.getHeaderStore();
        headerStore.addListener('load', this.onHeaderStoreLoad, this);
    },

    onLaunch: function () {
    },

    onHeaderStoreLoad: function (store, records, successful) {
        if (successful) {
            var headerContent = store.first().data.html;
            var headerView = this.getHeaderView();
            headerView.setInnerHtml(headerContent);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my view code:

```
Ext.define(appName + '.view.main.Header', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.header',

    height: 30,
    layout: 'border',
    border: false,

    items: [
        { html: 'header', region: 'center' } // this is just a temporary placeholder and I'd like to replace this item with different html
    ],

    setInnerHtml: function (html) {
        this.update(html); // doesn't work
    }
});
```

How do I need to change my `setInnerHtml` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mix items/html, at least not at the same time, so you either need to:

1) Call update of the first child of the header

```
this.items.first().update(html);
```

2) Remove the child items altogether

The second is preferable, since having an extra child component serves no purpose, nor does have a border layout with a single, center child region.

Comment: Evan - seems like the guy had a layout issue (thus I believe the container was never visible in the first place). Based on my own answer / comments which I deleted.

Comment: And by the way, not sure your answer is correct. I don't think he had sub-items at all. And this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/2YnmG/2/) works fine.

Comment: The question was a bit vague, but my statement still stands. If you create a container with a bunch of child items then use update() on the container, you overwrite all the components without cleaning them up.